# Ghee is used to cook the curry in.Ghee is used to make curry

Tags: usage

Ghee is used to cook the curry in.

Ghee is used to make curry.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: Which sentence do you think is correct and why? Explain what you think each means and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Have to admit I had to look up what "ghee" was...

Comment: *cooking* or *making* something is fine...and *ghee* is a liquid butter used in cooking. **So**, it's fine! :)

Comment: Please read the "Details, please" link (along with the answers there, plus the links contained in those answers) before you ask your next question. We get way too many questions here like this one: Nothing more than two sentences, and the question, "Which of these is correct?" Oftentimes, both are right or both are wrong; other times, either could be right but the sentence probably doesn't mean what the O.P. is trying to say. You owe it to the community to at least explain what you're trying to say, and tell us why you have questions about the way you've worded it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct grammatically but the meaning is different.

> Ghee is used to cook the curry in.

Here, ghee is a liquid that the food is cooked in. This is like:

> Broth is used to cook chicken in.

You don't eat or drink the broth (mostly).

> Ghee is used to make curry.

This is saying ghee is an ingredient. This is like:

> Sugar **is used/is an ingredient** in cookies.

To say more requires more context but is likely to become a cooking question.

Comment: ...so if the ghee becomes incorporated (mixed into) the curry, you are no longer cooking the curry "in" ghee.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock In that case it could be both. What you are actually trying to say would depend on additional context,

Comment: I didn't read the first sentence the way you did. I took it to mean that ghee is used to make the curry flavor stronger. Moreover, if it has the intended meaning that you discuss, it should be rewritten – it should be _The chicken is cooked in broth_, not _Broth is used to cook the chicken in_.